# Custom link help

Tags: formula

I'm trying to make a zillow link for a property...

Property object:

> Property Street: 4 tree rd
>
> Property City: thetown
>
> Property State: NY
>
> Property Zip: 12345

should result in the following URL:

https://www.zillow.com/homes/4%20tree%20rd%20thetown%20NY%2012345_rb/

I need all spaces in the URL escaped. I've tried various combinations of the URLENCODED and SUBTITUTE functions and i just cannot seem to get this one to work.

Comment: Can you share the formula that you have so far? `URLENCODE` should be the thing to use here. If you're stitching together multiple fields, it might be an issue with how you're concatenating things. Also might be helpful to see an example of the current output of your formula.

Comment: https://www.zillow.com/homes/{!URLENCODE(Property__c.Name)} {!URLENCODE(Property__c.City__c)} -> https://www.zillow.com/homes/467+KIPP+AVE%20HASBROUCK+HEIGHTS/

Comment: I need %20 chars for spaces

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information (more formatting options, and comments are best thought of as temproary)

Comment: Whenever i try to substitute any spaces with %20 it gives me %2520 instead which meas i'm double encoding the space from the understanding? When i use urlencode is just gives me +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it easiest to use the URLFOR syntax for complicated encoding problems. That looks like this:

```
{!URLFOR('https://www.zillow.com/homes/'&Account.BillingStreet&' '&
         Account.BillingState&' '&Account.BillingPostalCode)}
```

This should automatically encode everything properly for you. Adjust the field names as appropriate.